# Linking Cassandra/C++ driver Library in MATLAB MEX function

Tags: c++, matlab, cassandra

The basic idea is as follows: 
There is no Cassandra driver for MATLAB, but there is C++ Driver. Creating a project in VS12, I can query the database no problems.

I created a MEX file in MATLAB to call the gateway C++ function to get data from the database. Using MATLAB MEX:
1-Compiling the mex file and the gateway function works fine with no problems.
2-The path to include files and Cassandra.lib files are correct.

Still, at the linkage stage, the cassandra classes can not be found:

```
mex ('-v',ipath_cassandra_code,ipath_cassandra, cSourceFile,'accessCassandra.cpp','-lcassandra','-lcassandra_static')
```

getFromCassandra.cpp: gateway function to Cassandra
accessCassandra.cpp: MATLAB mex file calling getFromCassandraRes() in gateway getFromCassandra.cpp file

The error I get:

```
       Creating library getFromCassandra.lib and object getFromCassandra.exp
getFromCassandra.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol cass_cluster_new referenced in function "class
std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __cdecl getFromCassandraRes(char *,char *,int,int,class
std::vector<struct muStatsStruct,class std::allocator<struct muStatsStruct> > &)"
```

I am using the C++ Cassandra driver binary for my 64 bit windows.
MATLAB version: 8.5.0.197613 (R2015a)
Cassandra/C++ driver: Latest from http://datastax.github.io/cpp-driver/

Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Solved!

I tried to rebuild the Cassandra/C++ Driver on Windows. It needed many tools to be installed and failed at the end.

But the problem was solved when I noticed that:

In my Visual Studio project, I was building for win32 and ,thus, was using

```
\cassandra-cpp-driver-2.4.2-win32-msvc120\lib'
```

But MATLAB was building for 64bit!
So, when I changed the path to use the 64bit version of cassandra.lib:

```
\cassandra-cpp-driver-2.4.2-win64-msvc120\lib'
```

It worked!

I hope this saves others the hours I spent chasing this!